# How to maintain two versions of an app (pro and lite) in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am building an app in Flutter. I need to make two versions of it - a pro and lite version. I use Android Studio. What would be the best way to maintain two versions of an app, so I don't have to create two different projects and update the code in both projects ?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using [Flavors](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) where you can create 2 binaries from the same code base with different app ids. Anotehr way, although not tried myself you can use the flutter tools to [create multiple different builds](https://itnext.io/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d) for each platform.

From there you can have 2 entry main files that will be configured for each flavor, `main.dart` and `main_lite.dart`. In there you can specify what features are enabled for each one

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with an app for work. The solution I am using is to simply have a singe project for both apps but a special gitHub branch for the 2nd app.

So for instance my main app is on `master` and the 2nd app is on the `second_app` branch.

When I make a significant change, I make sure to merge it in master first.
And then I just git merge master into `second_app`.

So, it's not 100% automatic, but it works fine for most cases. And you have the whole git merge workflow at your disposal so you can easily resolve conflicts when you merge.